# maintain distinct results with table join

Tags: sql-server

I have a relatively simple query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tA.id   AS 'id'
    //as pointed out, I could just select tB.value without the case here
    ,CASE   WHEN  tB.udf_id IN ('1')
            THEN  tB.value
     END    AS 'side'
FROM tableA tA
INNER JOIN tableB   tB  ON  tA.id    = tB.id
WHERE tB.udf_id IN ('1')
```

```
tableA
|id| date     |
|--|----------|
|1 | 1/1/2023 |
|2 | 1/2/2023 |
|3 | 1/3/2023 |

tableB
|id|udf_id| value   |
|--|------|---------|
|1 | 1    | right   |
|1 | 2    | active  |
|2 | 1    | left    |
|2 | 2    | NULL    |
|3 | 3    | right   |
|3 | 3    | pending |
```

This will give me 1 row per "id" because of the WHERE clause.

```
Result Output
|id| value   |
|--|---------|
|1 | right   |
|2 | left    |
|3 | right   |
```

However, I now want to add another condition to what data gets returned.
I only want to return results;

```
tB.value is not NULL when tB.udf_id=2
(pseudocode, I know this doesn't work this way)
```

So the new result output would look the same but drop id=2 because tb.value=NULLwhen tb.udf_id=2.

```
New Result Output
|id| value   |
|--|---------|
|1 | right   |
|3 | right   |
```

I'm struggling on how to do this. Just adding another udf_id value creates multiple rows of results instead of the one, which I don't want. And I don't believe I can express my codition in the WHERE clause like that.

My assumption is that I need to do some sort of subquery?

Comment: Why use the same condition in Where and When? To add your new condition you have to remove the existing condition since they are contradicting.

Comment: can you add the output of your current query and the desired output?

Comment: @Orion447 I've updated the question with the current result output and the desired result output. As you will see the goal is to drop id=2 because in tableB when udf_id=2 it has a NULL value

Comment: @NoChance If I remove the existing condition in the WHERE clause, tB.udf_id IN (1), then I will get duplicate rows in my results because the JOIN sees the id match multiple times in tableB. That's why that WHERE clause was initially added. Obviously it contradicts what I want to CHANGE the query to now. Removing or changing it to tb.udf_id IN (1,2) doesn't give me what I want, it just creates multiple rows per ID. Thus the question. As to why the SELECT WHEN clause in the initial query, you are correct that it's not necessary with the existing WHERE clause and I could just return tB.value

Comment: @NoChance I had added the CASE WHEN in the select section of the query because I wanted to be explicit about what udf_id I was trying to return results for and thinking it would allow me to create another column for a different udf_id if I needed.  That doesn't really work though, just creates 2 columns each with NULL values in the others column.

Comment: Not sure if your specific question was actually answered above, so I'll throw my two cents in. Logically `(A when B)` is equivalent to `(B implies A)`, which is equivalent to `((NOT B) OR A)`. So substituting in your requested logic, `(tB.value is not NULL when tB.udf_id=2)` becomes `((NOT tB.udf_id=2) OR tB.value is not NULL)` which can also be written as `(tB.udf_id!=2 OR tB.value is not NULL)`. Bottom line, add `AND (tB.udf_id != 2 OR tB.value is not NULL)` to `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What is the primary key for tableb? If you want the value "right" from tableb, whey not just select it? Do you want the corresponding IDs for the value "right" in tableb from tablea?

Comment: @TN I tried what you suggested, and it still returns incorrect results that shouldn't be showing.

Comment: What are the values that are showing that shouldn't be showing - specifically what are `tB.udf_id` and `tB.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will check for `udf_id = '2'` without "joining" an extra set of records

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tA.id   AS 'id'
    //as pointed out, I could just select tB.value without the case here
    ,CASE   WHEN  tB.udf_id IN ('1')
            THEN  tB.value
     END    AS 'side'
FROM tableA tA
INNER JOIN tableB   tB  ON  tA.id    = tB.id
WHERE tB.udf_id IN ('1')
    -- This will check for non NULL udf_id = '2' value
    AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM tableB AS ID2 WHERE tA.id = ID2.id AND udf_id = '2' AND value IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked unlike just trying to just add simply conditions to the where clause. This stopped the returning of entries that had NULL in udf_id=2 while other recommendations didn't.